# correct way to implement multipule users registration form

Tags: 7, users

I want to create a site where users get to chose between being an employee or employer.

So when users first go to the registration they need to be asked which role will they be, and on that choice a different registration form will appear.

What would a good implementation method be?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module and create two separate profiles for employee and employer roles.

Then you can use module [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) or [Profile2 Registration Path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) to allow users select which role do they want to register with.

Comment: Seems like it could work, but I rather not work with profile2 module anymore, I got frustrated last time trying to make profile2 fields searchable.

Comment: "You may use Views and/or the Search API to provide listings or searches for profiles." Not to be smug but it's on the profile 2 description. I was curious about the question, and it might be a change in the description.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a multi-step form in a module that gives the user the opportunity to make that choice and once the form is completed by the user you could store the data.

Comment: Could you tell me more about your approach please?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1121110 examples of a form module. But if you create a module from the form api that answers the questions. When they got to sign up the form is a part of the process

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Field conditional state](http://drupal.org/project/field-conditional-state) module and Rules for this. Add a select list with employer and employee option and depending on which one the user selects, show or hide fields relevant for each role. Then create a rule that assigns new users a role based on the value of the select field that they selected.